# What to do with a constant term in a complex exponential when converting to trigonometric functions

Tags: trigonometry, complex-numbers, exponential-function

Given the complex exponential $e^{{jt}\theta+b}$ which is the correct way of treating the constant term when rewriting the exponential as a trigonometric function?

1. Treat  $\theta{t} + b$ as the $\omega$ term and rewrite as $\cos\left({\theta{t} + b}\right) + j\sin\left(\theta{t} + b\right)$
2. Treat b as part of the magnitude and rewrite as $e^b\left[{\cos\left({\theta{t}}\right) + j\sin\left(\theta{t}\right)}\right]$

My intuition says that 2 should be the correct way, but I can't find a clear definition in my notes or text books.

Comment: Hint: $$e^{a+b}=e^ae^b$$

Comment: @Pixel I'm aware of the identity, that's where answer possibility 2 comes from. I take from your hint that you are suggesting answer 2 is the correct way.

Comment: it's 2 just use the above to prove it

Comment: Yes it's 2 for that reason :-) and  then just use $e^{jx}=\cos x+j\sin x$.

Comment: @richbai90 $\displaystyle\;\cos\left({\theta{t} + b}\right) + j\sin\left(\theta{t} + b\right)$ $=e^{j\left(\theta{t} + b\right)}\ne e^{j\theta{t}+b}=e^{j\theta{t}}\,e^b\,$.